# Accessing a clone of SVN server data

Tags: svn, backups

I have a backup, a mirror of an SVN server data area, containing a number of repositories.  The server has been kaputt for several years, it was a CollabNet SVN Edge installation. In the distant past, I occasionally had to recover the repositories under new CollabNet installations. Simply moving the data directories into the proper space was adequate to move the repositories to new digs.

Question: Is there a reasonable path to access these data areas, without recreating a server? That is, could I use TortoiseSVN (for example) to access these repositories directly, without a server?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about using some tool. Such questions are on topic only if they cover how the tool integrates into some development *process* – after all, this site is about Software Engineering. See our [help/on-topic] for details. Please read: [Where does my tool question go?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7253) Usage of development tools is on topic on Stack Overflow. For general purpose tools go to Super User.

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer**

Yes, it is. If you **really** have *repository tree* inside backup, you can extract it to any location (on local drive) and access repository, using local TSVN and `file:///` protocol